# Remove all focus borders from JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, focus, border

While working with JavaFX, I found the focus border to be hindering on some visual nodes, like buttons and certain panes. Other questions on this topic on SO often suggest adding the following css (overriding the defaults from Modena.css, the default stylesheet for JavaFX 8) to your style file:

```
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
```

At first glance, this removes the focus borders, but after some use I found that some UI elements were missing more than just that blue glow. After going through modena, I found that this is because of the way a lot of the nodes are drawn: many of them have a background color consisting of multiple boxes stacked on top of each other with different insets and radii, resulting in a border-like look.

I have also found that this background color derives from the previously mentioned properties for drawing a border. Hence setting the colors to transparent has the unintended effect that certain nodes (like panes, comboboxes, ...) show a border when not focused, but not anymore when they are focused, due to the way the background color is derived for the `:focused` pseudo-class.

Is it possible to remove the focus border (and faint focus border) so they retain the look of an unfocused element when they are in fact focused?

Answer (score 12):

I've compiled a solution where the focus border is removed by combining what I found on SO by overriding more parts of modena: I've chosen to override the properties of the ":focused" pseudo-class by those of the non-focused defaults for button-like and pane-like things (as stated in modena itself). The results are:

```
.button:focused,
.toggle-button:focused,
.radio-button:focused > .radio,
.check-box:focused > .box,
.menu-button:focused,
.choice-box:focused,
.color-picker.split-button:focused > .color-picker-label,
.combo-box-base:focused,
.slider:focused .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
}

.scroll-pane:focused,
.split-pane:focused,
.list-view:focused,
.tree-view:focused,
.table-view:focused,
.tree-table-view:focused,
.html-editor:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-padding: 1;
}

.radio-button > .radio, .radio-button:focused > .radio  {   
    -fx-background-radius: 1.0em; /* large value to make sure this remains circular */    
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em; /* 4 -- padding from outside edge to the inner black dot */ 
}
.split-menu-button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border; 
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 3;
}
.split-menu-button:focused > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color; 
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 1, 2 1 2 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 2 0 0 2, 1 0 0 1;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.667em 0.333333em 0.667em; /* 4 8 4 8 */
}
.split-menu-button:focused > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color; 
    -fx-background-insets: 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.5em 0.667em 0.5em 0.667em; /* 6 8 6 8 */
}

.scroll-bar:focused {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-box-border,30%), linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,-3%), derive(-fx-base,5%) 50%, derive(-fx-base,-3%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 0;
}
.scroll-bar:vertical:focused {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-box-border,30%), linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,-3%), derive(-fx-base,5%) 50%, derive(-fx-base,-3%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;
}

.text-input:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: -fx-accent;
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}

.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 4px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -8%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
}

.titled-pane:focused > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
}

.color-picker.split-button:focused > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 1 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0, 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
}
```

Basically what it does it change the rendering of the background color to draw the same look and feel whether the UI node has focus or not.